# C# Clicking LI in UL for web scaping purposes.

Tags: javascript, c#, html, automation, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape a page : https://www.investing.com/equities/statoil-technical

What I want to achieve is clicking on the 5 mins, 15 min, 30 mins etc bottons and read the Pivot Points table that changes after the clicks.

I have tried many different approaches. 
System.Windows.Forms.Browser, ChromiumWebBrowser (Cef) and now ChromiumWebBrowser with JavaScript.

Like this :

```
         script = " var ul = document.getElementById('pairSublinksLevel1'); " +
            " var items = ul.getElementsByTagName('li'); " +
            " var Financials = 0; " +

            // Find and click the Financials Botton
            " for (var o = 0; o < items.length; o++) " +
            " { " +
            "   if (items[o].textContent = 'Financials') {" +
            "   Financials = o;}" +
            " } " +
            " items[Financials].click() ; " +

            // should I set " setTimeout(function(){}, 3000); " ?

            " var lis = document.getElementById('pairSublinksLevel1').getElementsByTagName('li'); " +
            " var TechnicalAnalysis = 0; " +

            // Find and click the Technical Analysis sub menu
            " for (var o = 0; o < lis.length; o++) " +
            " { " +
            "   if (lis[o].textContent = 'Technical Analysis') {" +
            "   TechnicalAnalysis = o;}" +
            " } " +

            " lis[TechnicalAnalysis].click();" +
            // should I set " setTimeout(function(){}, 3000); " ?


            // Get the bottons ( 5mins, 15mins, 30mins etc)
            " var TimePeriods = document.getElementById('timePeriodsWidget').getElementsByTagName('li'); " +
            " TimePeriods[5].click(); " +
            // should I set " setTimeout(function(){}, 3000); " ?

            " var x = document.getElementById('curr_table'); " + 
            " var xHTML= x.innerHTML ;";

            var task = LocalBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script, timeout);
            task.Wait();
```

The problem is that xHTML does not change when I alter the " TimePeriods[5].click(); to button 3 or 1 or whatever.

I have tried this in DOM. I have tried in the browser. 
I am stuck.

Could someone tip me in the right direction? 
Showing me how to click the LI in :

```
<ul class="tabsBoxSubMenu techStudiesTabsSubMenu innerPage " id="timePeriodsWidget" data-view="normal">
<li pairid="376" data-period="300" class="first">
<li pairid="376" data-period="900" class="">
<li pairid="376" data-period="1800" class="">
<li pairid="376" data-period="3600" class="selected ">
<li pairid="376" data-period="18000" class="">
<li pairid="376" data-period="86400" class="">
<li pairid="376" data-period="week" class="">
<li pairid="376" data-period="month" class="">
</ul>
```

and getting the

```
<table class="genTbl closedTbl crossRatesTbl" id="curr_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="first left noWrap">Name</th>
<th class="noWrap">S3</th>
<th class="noWrap">S2</th>
<th class="noWrap">S1</th>
<th class="noWrap">Pivot Points</th>
<th class="noWrap">R1</th>
<th class="noWrap">R2</th>
<th class="noWrap">R3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</table>
```

that the code the LI click generates?

Thanks
Håkon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to click the `LI` element, but the action to load the table and change the HTML is actually triggered by the child `A` element of the `LI`.

So, something like: `TimePeriods[5].children[0].click();` would do the job.

> // should I set " setTimeout(function(){}, 3000); " ?

Yes, you could use `setTimeout` to delay the crawling of the data in the table or use some sort of DOM change detection technique, as the click triggers an AJAX call and the data in the table will most probably not be available immediately.

Anyway, I have to advise you to crawl [politely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Politeness_policy) as the process can overload the target websites and there could be even legal implications.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will not crowd the site with requests. 

I have never thought of calling the childrens click. Thank you for that. 
After a quick look it does not seem to change the result, but I will look more into it. 

Thank you, 
Håkon

Comment: I have tried the example I used in my post.
I have also tried clicking children in DOM. 

But, the innerHTML seems to be the same. Looks like the buttons script does not run. 

But thanks for the effort.
Regards, 
Håkon

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I was so fixed at looking at getting the result page from the JavaScript that it took me some time to think of looking at the script in the browser!

Thank you for setting me in the right direction and do not worry about the legal issue. It is for personal use and probably 15-30 calls a day.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved your problem. Please mark the answer appropriately if it did indeed help you with your issue.

As a side note, I got very good results using PhantomJS for website automation. The .NET integrated browser lacked rendering support for JavaScript in some situations. Haven't used Cef, it appeared rather cumbersome to use for simple cases.